# how to separate comma separated values in oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to separate the value of a column by commas.

Example: `BCDEY`; I need to convert to a `B, C, D, E, Y`.
Follows the "select":

```
SELECT CDGRUPOCONDICAO FROM TBINTCLIENTE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try also this:

```
with cad as  
(select 'BCDEY' cad from dual)
select regexp_replace (regexp_replace(cad,'(.)','\1, '),', $','') cad_comma from cad;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that maybe?

```
with testdata as (select 'BCDEY' str from dual)

select listagg(c, ', ') within group(order by lvl)
from (
  select substr(str, level, 1) c,
         level lvl
  from testdata
  connect by level <= length(str)
  )
```

Producing:

```
B, C, D, E, Y
```

Here, the subquery split the string character by character. Then the outer [`listagg`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions089.htm) re-assemble the items by joining them with `', '`.

Answer (score 1):

An other solution, using [recursive subquery factoring](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_recursive_subquery_factoring_with_clause.htm) (hence, assuming oracle >= 11g release 2):

```
with testdata as (select 1 id, 'BCDEY' str from dual union all
                  select 2, 'ABC' from dual),
--                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--                 replace that subquery by your actual query
     splited(c,r,id,lvl) as (
                  select '' c, str r, id, 0 lvl from testdata
                  union all
                  select substr(r, 1, 1) c,
                         substr(r, 2) r,
                         id,
                         lvl+1
                  from splited
                  where r is not null)

select listagg(c, ', ') within group(order by lvl)
from splited
group by (id)
```

Producing:

```
LISTAGG(C,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYLVL)
B, C, D, E, Y
A, B, C
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/38971